# Menu CSS issue in IE8

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-8

I have created a Menu list.
It is working perfectly on Chrome and Firefox but misaligned in IE8

Chrome Snapshot :-
http://postimg.org/image/g6uf9zikr/
[image: chrome snapshot]

IE8 Snapshot :-
http://postimg.org/image/u6o3pzasz/
[image: IE8 snapshot]

Here's my CSS ------

```css
div.menu {
 background-color:#383838;
 height:65px;
 margin-bottom:20px;
}
div.menu ul {
 vertical-align:middle;
 list-style:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
div.menu ul li {
 float:left;
 display:block;
}
div.menu ul li a {
 color:#FFFFFF;
 display:block;
 float:left;
 font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding:24px 20px 22px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 text-decoration:none;
}
div.menu ul li a:hover {
 text-decoration:underline;
 background-color:#2B2B2B;
}

div.menu ul li:hover ul {
 display:block;
}

div.menu ul li ul {
 vertical-align:middle;
 text-align:center;
 float: none;
 list-style: none;
 display: none;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:999;
 margin-top:60px;
 background-color:#383838;
 opacity:0.8;
}

div.menu ul li ul li{
 float: none;
 vertical-align:middle;
 background-color:#383838;
 padding:15px;
}
div.menu ul li ul li a {
 color:#FFFFFF;
 font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial;
 font-weight:bold;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 padding:0px;
}
div.menu ul li ul li a:hover {
 text-decoration:underline;
}

div.menu ul li ul li:hover{
 background-color:#2B2B2B;
 opacity:1.0;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php"> HOME </a></li>
<li><a href="">CONTROLLER</a>
<ul>
<li><a href=""> CONTROLLER-1</a></li>
<li><a href=""> CONTROLLER-2</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li><a href="">IOS BPL ZIO</a>
<ul>
<li><a href=""> IOS BPL ZIO-1</a></li>
<li><a href=""> IOS BPL ZIO-2</a></li>
</ul></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Please post your HTML as well. If the runnable code snippet would actually run, that would be great.

Comment: HTML -
http://justpaste.it/lici

Comment: Next time, please edit it in your question. I did that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `float: left` from the links in the menu. This will cause those links to fill  the entire row, and the `ul` of the submenu will not be shown next to it.

To counter that gap that causes, remove the `margin-top` from the submenu `ul`.

That should do the trick, although I don't have IE8 at hand to test it.

```css
div.menu {
 background-color:#383838;
 height:65px;
 margin-bottom:20px;
}
div.menu ul {
 vertical-align:middle;
 list-style:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
div.menu ul li {
 float:left;
 display:block;
}
div.menu ul li a {
 color:#FFFFFF;
 display:block;
 font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding:24px 20px 22px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 text-decoration:none;
}
div.menu ul li a:hover {
 text-decoration:underline;
 background-color:#2B2B2B;
}

div.menu ul li:hover ul {
 display:block;
}

div.menu ul li ul {
 vertical-align:middle;
 text-align:center;
 float: none;
 list-style: none;
 display: none;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:999;
 background-color:#383838;
 opacity:0.8;
}

div.menu ul li ul li{
 float: none;
 vertical-align:middle;
 background-color:#383838;
 padding:15px;
}
div.menu ul li ul li a {
 color:#FFFFFF;
 font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial;
 font-weight:bold;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 padding:0px;
}
div.menu ul li ul li a:hover {
 text-decoration:underline;
}

div.menu ul li ul li:hover{
 background-color:#2B2B2B;
 opacity:1.0;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php"> HOME </a></li>
<li><a href="">CONTROLLER</a>
<ul>
<li><a href=""> CONTROLLER-1</a></li>
<li><a href=""> CONTROLLER-2</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li><a href="">IOS BPL ZIO</a>
<ul>
<li><a href=""> IOS BPL ZIO-1</a></li>
<li><a href=""> IOS BPL ZIO-2</a></li>
</ul></li>
</ul>
</div>
```